# Completion of sigma field

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$  is a probability space.
Show that 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}^*=\{A \cup N: A \in  \mathcal{A}, N \in \mathcal{N} \}
\end{align}
is a sigma algebra and where $\mathcal{N}$ is a subset of all negligible sets.

I am stuck no a part where I have to show that if $B \in \mathcal{A}^*$ then $B^c \in \mathcal{A}^*$.
I was thinking we can write $B^c=(A \cup N)^c=A^c \cap N^c$. But is $N^c \in \mathcal{A}^*$???
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that a null set is a subset of a null set in your $\sigma$-algebra.
If $N\in \mathcal N$ then there is a $M\in \mathcal A\cap\mathcal N$ so that $N\subseteq M$. Now, $(A\cup M)^c\cup (M\setminus N)=(A\cup N)^c$, where $(A\cup M)^c\in\mathcal A$ and $(M\setminus N)\in\mathcal N$.

Comment: How would you show that $\mathcal A^*$ is complete in a sense that every negligible set is null? Thank you for you help.